# How do I include all max values within a row?

Tags: sqlite, count, max, groupwise-maximum

I'm very new to learning SQL, I apologize if my question isn't completely accurate.

The question I'm trying to answer with this query is "What is the most popular music genre in each country?" I've had to use a subquery and it works, but I found that for a few countries in the table, more than one genre has the MAX value.  I'm stuck with how to edit my query so that all genres with the max value show in the results. Here is my code, using DB Browser for SQLite:

```
SELECT BillingCountry AS Country , name AS Genre , MAX(genre_count) AS Purchases
FROM (
    SELECT i.BillingCountry, g.name, COUNT(g.genreid) AS genre_count
FROM Invoice i
JOIN InvoiceLine il
ON il.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
JOIN TRACK t
ON il.trackid = t.TrackId
JOIN Genre g
ON t.genreid = g.GenreId
GROUP BY 1,2
) sub
GROUP BY 1
```

Here is an example of the result:

```
| Country | Genre |Purchase|
|---------|-------|--------|
|Agrentina|  Punk |   9    |
|Australia|  Rock |   22   |
```

BUT in running just the subquery to COUNT the purchases, Argentina has two Genres with 9 Purchases (the max number for that country). How do I adjust my query to include both and not just the first one in the row?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: Great. Another stick, with no lollipop.

Comment: See the tag I added.

Comment: @ysth I'm using DB Browser for SQLite Version 3.12.1, Qt Version 5.12.8
SQLite Version 3.33.0

Comment: so this is sqlite, not mysql?

Comment: @ysth that is correct. I realize I incorrectly tagged with mysql and have since changed that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT BillingCountry, name, genre_count
FROM (
  SELECT i.BillingCountry, g.name, COUNT(*) AS genre_count,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.BillingCountry ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
  FROM Invoice i
  INNER JOIN InvoiceLine il ON il.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
  INNER JOIN TRACK t ON il.trackid = t.TrackId
  INNER JOIN Genre g ON t.genreid = g.GenreId
  GROUP BY i.BillingCountry, g.name
)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

This will return the ties in separate rows.

If you want 1 row for each country, you could also use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT BillingCountry, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name, MAX(genre_count) AS genre_count
FROM (
  SELECT i.BillingCountry, g.name, COUNT(*) AS genre_count,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.BillingCountry ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
  FROM Invoice i
  INNER JOIN InvoiceLine il ON il.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
  INNER JOIN TRACK t ON il.trackid = t.TrackId
  INNER JOIN Genre g ON t.genreid = g.GenreId
  GROUP BY i.BillingCountry, g.name
)
WHERE rnk = 1
GROUP BY BillingCountry
```